# How can i get coordinates in the route path in google map?

Tags: google-maps

if using the link like this

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=25.04202,121.534761
&daddr=25.05202,121.554761&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
```

it will return the value of coordinates as below:

> 121.534760,25.042040,0.000000
>   121.533650,25.042190,0.000000 121.532950,25.042430,0.000000 121.532950,25.042430,0.000000 121.532980,25.044400,0.000000 121.532980,25.044400,0.000000 121.534000,25.044670,0.000000 121.534400,25.044820,0.000000 121.535690,25.045690,0.000000 121.536400,25.045990,0.000000 121.540510,25.046700,0.000000 121.543860,25.047490,0.000000 121.546430,25.048160,0.000000 121.549130,25.048140,0.000000 121.549130,25.048140,0.000000 121.550770,25.048110,0.000000 121.552570,25.048140,0.000000 121.552570,25.048140,0.000000 121.552700,25.049850,0.000000 121.552750,25.051440,0.000000 121.552650,25.051540,0.000000 121.552640,25.051680,0.000000 121.552640,25.051680,0.000000 121.552660,25.052280,0.000000 121.552660,25.052280,0.000000 121.553770,25.052260,0.000000 121.553770,25.052260,0.000000 121.554770,25.052240,0.000000

but in my javascript, it returned roughly just a few coordinates, 5-6 coordinates

Here is my code to get coordinates :

```
function route(FromPlace,ToPlace){
if(!FromPlace&&!ToPlace){
    FromPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(13.692941, 100.750723);
    ToPlace = document.getElementById("endPoint").value;
}
    //directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var request = {
            origin: FromPlace,
            destination: ToPlace,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {

            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
             for (var j = 0; j < response.routes[0].legs[i].steps.length; j++) {
                 if(j == response.routes[0].legs[i].steps.length-1){

                    addressRoute = addressRoute+response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].end_point.lat()+","
                      +response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].end_point.lng()+"";
                    latitude = response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].end_point.lat();
                    longitude = response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].end_point.lng();
                    destinationDB = latitude +","+ longitude;
                    }else{

                    addressRoute = addressRoute+response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].end_point.lat()+","
                      +response.routes[0].legs[i].steps[j].end_point.lng()+"|";

                    }
                 }
            }   
            //document.getElementById("textLocation").innerHTML = addressRoute;
        }
      }); 
   }
```

How can i improve my code to get coordinates more specific like the link above?
is there any suggestion? :)

Comment: Are you asking for a greater degree of precision? That is, degrees:minutes:seconds.

Answer (score 2):

what you need is not the steps[j].start_point and steps[j].end_point but the path object contained in each step object. that is to say:

```
route.legs.forEach(function(leg){
    leg.steps.forEach(function(step){
        step.path.forEach(function(point){
            debug_panel.innerHTML+=point+"<br/>";
        });
    });
});
```

you want to get each and every point in all of your steps' paths as well, not only the start and end points.

hope that helps